# 2 numbers not adding together correctly

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm using repl.it database for a discord economy bot that i'm making. I made a withdraw command, but when I type `!withdraw 10` I'm expecting to receive `currentbalance + amount` (like if current balance is 50 and i typed `!with` 100 I should get 150) but I keep getting `"50100"`. Here is my code:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("#ايداع")) {
    const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);

    let money = await db.get(`wallet_${message.member}`)
    let currentbalance1 = await db.get(`wallet_${message.member}`)
    let currentbalance = await db.get(`bank_${message.member}`)
    let gembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("RED")
      .setDescription("ليس لديك مبلغ كافي للايداع")


    let cembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("RED")
      .setDescription("يرجى تحديد مبلغ للايداع");

    let amount = args[1];
    if (!amount || isNaN(amount))
        return message.reply(cembed);

    await db.set(`bank_${message.member}`, currentbalance + amount);
    await db.set(`wallet_${message.member}`, currentbalance1 - amount)

    let sembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("RED")
      .setDescription("لقد قمت بايداع" + amount + "الى حسابك البنكي");

    message.channel.send(sembed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your output is `50100` from `50 + 100` it means that your numbers (`50` and `100`) are strings not numbers. A simple solution would be to use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Example:

```js
let currentbalance1 = await db.get(`wallet_${message.member}`);
let currentbalance = await db.get(`bank_${message.member}`);

await db.set(`bank_${message.member}`, parseInt(currentbalance) + parseInt(amount));
await db.set(`wallet_${message.member}`, parseInt(currentbalance1) - parseInt(amount));
```

Full example:

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("#ايداع")) {
    const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);

    let money = await db.get(`wallet_${message.member}`)
    let currentbalance1 = await db.get(`wallet_${message.member}`)
    let currentbalance = await db.get(`bank_${message.member}`)
    let gembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("RED")
      .setDescription("ليس لديك مبلغ كافي للايداع")
    let cembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("RED")
      .setDescription("يرجى تحديد مبلغ للايداع");

    let amount = args[1];
    if (!amount || isNaN(amount)) return message.reply(cembed);

    await db.set(`bank_${message.member}`, parseInt(currentbalance) + parseInt(amount));
    await db.set(`wallet_${message.member}`, parseInt(currentbalance1) - parseInt(amount))

    let sembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RED")
        .setDescription("لقد قمت بايداع" + amount + "الى حسابك البنكي");

    message.channel.send(sembed);
}
```